# How Do I Turn HTML Text into a Javascript Variable While Removing Line Breaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I have a raw feed of some text within the body tag of an HTML page. I need to run a function on it to turn it into a Javascript string variable. However, there are literal line breaks in the HTML page (which are obviously not permissible in JS strings).

Here's an example of the source of the page I'm working with:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
BLDG||0|EOR|

PLNC||0|EOR|

SUBD|Pine Manor|1|EOR|

CITY|Fort Myers|1|EOR|

</body>
```

jQuery is permissible.
How do I turn this all into a Javascript variable while removing the literal line breaks so that the variables work?

Comment: What do you mean literal line breaks aren't permissible in JS strings? What happened to "Line1\nLine2"?

Comment: Line breaks are perfectly valid inside a JavaScript variable. They are not valid inside a string constant (unless in escaped form: \n). I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```